# Loading javascript in an iFrame on different subdomains

Tags: javascript, iframe, subdomain, ckeditor

I have a javascript function that loads CKEditor in one of my iFrames.  Problem is that my iFrame is located on a different subdomain.  I fixed this by using document.domain, however my CKeditor only loads sometimes.  Does anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: The `<iframe>` tag is not an Apple product.  _Please_ don't write iFrame.

Comment: Do you have any javascript errors when it fails to load?

Comment: Whoops, I'll remember to never do that again.
Yup, I get an "Permission denied for <ULR> to get property Window.document from <URL>"

Answer (score 0):

I've not tested it myself, but give this a try : **[iframe-xdr](http://code.google.com/p/iframe-xdr/)**